# my mediaplayer starts a new instance instead of stopping

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

im making a media player that plays mp3s mixes stored on firebase. i can make the links play no problem. but when i press the item again i want it to be the equivalent of pressing stop. but for some reason it does not stop it starts a new instance of the media. can some one tell me what ive done wrong please.

my code

in my on create

```
mMediaplayer = null;
```

then my method

```
 private void fetchAudioUrlFromFirebase() throws IOException {
    String mp3 = mp3url;

    mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaplayer.setDataSource(mp3);
    mMediaplayer.prepare();//prepare to play
    if (mMediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
        stopPlaying();
    } else {
        playMedia();
    }



}

private void stopPlaying() {

    if (mMediaplayer != null) {
        mMediaplayer.stop();
    }
}


private void playMedia() {

        mMediaplayer.start();
    }
}
```

then in item onclick

```
 try {
         fetchAudioUrlFromFirebase();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

issue : lets assume media player is already playing so

```
// song is playing
mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(); // you created a new player
mMediaplayer.setDataSource(mp3);
mMediaplayer.prepare();//prepare to play
if (mMediaplayer.isPlaying()) { // new player is not in playing state
    stopPlaying();              // so you always checking the state of new player
} else {
    playMedia();
}
```

check first then create

```
if (mMediaplayer!=null && mMediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
    stopPlaying();
} 
mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaplayer.setDataSource(mp3);
mMediaplayer.prepare();//prepare to play
playMedia();
```

so the logic can be reduced to

```
if (mMediaplayer!=null && mMediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
    mMediaplayer.stop();
    mMediaplayer.release();
} 
mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaplayer.setDataSource(mp3);
mMediaplayer.prepare();//prepare to play
mMediaplayer.start();
```

Comment: so can i get rid of the bit in stopPlaying() method

Comment: i am glad that i could help , you can simply try the 3rd part of the code to get rid of both function but later when you will add more complexity by adding new features then it will be easy to maintain small function rather than a big one

Comment: ok so now it dosent start a new instance it restarts the current mp3. @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: yes ,it should , so you want to stop the song in case of the same song and play the other one if it is different ?